# JQuery Toggle auto-collapsing div on load. Don't want it to, can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I didn't see any answer to this question out there, but I'm having this problem:

I made a JQuery menu UI, and it was working just fine.

When you click on the first link inside an list-item, the list-item is supposed to expand to show the rest of the links.

However! When the page loads, it seems the .toggle() which is connected to the first link is auto-collapsing that first link. I can't figure it out.

Again, to reitterate: The first link "a.cat" is being collapsed when the page loads. It didn't used to, and I'm not sure when, or if, I even changed it...).

**Edit** [Here's the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/g2avityhitz/acraZ/5/)

Anyhow, I hope that's clear enough. I'll check back regularly to answer questions.

And here's the JS, because S.O. requires it:

```
$("#sidebar ul li a.cat").toggle( function () {

    $(this).stop(true).animate({
        "color" : "#fff"
    });

    var growTo = (parseInt($(this).siblings("a.link").length) * nmMenu.linkHeight) + nmMenu.catHeight;

    $(this).parent("li").stop(true).animate({
        "height"        : growTo + "px",
        "padding-top"   : "5px"
    }, function () {
        $(this).children("a").stop(true).animate({
            "margin-left"   : "20px"
        });
    });

}, function () {

    $(this).siblings("a").andSelf().stop(true).animate({
        "margin-left"   : "0px"
    }, function () {
        $(this).siblings(" a:first").stop(true).animate({
            "margin-bottom" : nmMenu.catMarginBottom + "px",
            "color" : nmMenu.linkColor
        }); 

        $(this).parent("li").stop(true).animate({
            "height"    : nmMenu.catHeight + "px"
        });
    });
```

Comment: [Updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/acraZ/1/) since yours was calling MooTools (top left). Is this one working correctly?

Comment: @Blazemonger I updated it. Same issues. >_<